# Which is the better platform to learn UNIX/Linux (Kali Linux Vs. Red Hat or other)

Tags: python, linux, unix

I just started a new semester and I started my UNIX class yesterday. I've already decided to use python along with my learning process but what I really want to use with it is Kali as my UNIX/Linux platform to learn off of since I already wanted to learn Cyber Sec. anyways. I just wanted to know if this is a good combo or is Red Hat Ent. or something else much more feasible?

I was thinking since it's all Linux, why should it even matter?

Please give me your thoughts and opinion!!!

Thank You
AO!

Comment: Yes it is all Linux. Download and Install Fedora latest version

Answer (score 2):

If you want to learn Linux for real, I recommend Gentoo. You'll have to do everything by hand, and get familiar with every configuration file and tool there is. You'll have no choice but to learn.

It's a slow process, but if you're eager to learn, you'll enjoy it. That's how I learned!

Hope it helps

Comment: Please do not answer off-topic questions like this.  It only encourages people to ask more like them.

Comment: Sorry about that,, because i am new in stack overflow and i don't know about the rules

Comment: @Mobitips fair point :) Do check the help center, mainly http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic. The problem with answering these is that, even if the OP's question gets put on hold and/or closed, he gets "rewarded" for his bad behavior. He gets his answer even if the question shouldn't reside on stack. It's not a big deal, we've all done it :) Just try to be more careful in the future ^^. On another note.... Welcome to StackOverflow!

Comment: dude i dont even know what the frick you people are talking about "bad behavior" i just typed in a question and clicked. If you want people to know they're doing something wrong simply just tell them and they'll know. don't be a stuck up prick about it (now thats behaving badly if you think about it).So  SOO-freakin-RY!.